# Write to Core Data context without notification from observer

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnotificationcenter, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` observer that modifies a record directly after it has been saved. As imagined I am having an infinite loop issue where modifying the newly saved record will trigger another notification to the observer.

My thought would be to track the ID of the Core Data record and when it comes back around I simply ignore it and remove the ID from the array. This would work but I am worried about collisions, it seems highly unlikely but still possible that collisions would occur which would cause a record that collides to miss the modifications from the observer.

What is the common knowledge solution here?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer seems to be to use `NSManagedObjectContextWillSave` instead of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`, so that you can make the change before saving and therefore avoid a loop. Unless there's some compelling reason you didn't mention, that's what I'd do.

Comment: Is it possible to get the data inserted/updated/deleted? In the docs it mentions that the userInfo dictionary holds no data for WillSave.